# SQL - have full range of dates when units id is null /0

Tags: sql-server

I am building a query to count the number of units of product a and product b and total value amount for a series of dates. Almost all days have one or more units of Product A but Product B can have 0 units in some days. I've JOINED Product B table with the Product A table on the date column. I've also used a WITH clause to count the number of Product B units. The aggregation of units is correct, however, I want to know how I can 'add' the days in the range below for instance that are not retrieved by the query, so days where there are no units of Product B - like 08/08/16, 10/08/16 as show in the table below ( the table below is the retrieved rows of the query).

```
date        unit_a   unit_b  amount
07/08/16    24         1     48
09/08/16    62         17   207
11/08/16    52         12   102
12/08/16    31         5    152
16/08/16    32         12   110
17/08/16    30         3    120
18/08/16    43         41   315
19/08/16    20         1    50.12
21/08/16    19         12   48
22/08/16    35         1    32
```

Here is an example of the query I am trying to create:

```
with prod_a as(
    select cast(a.date_started as date) as a_date,
    count(a.id) as id_a
    from table_a a
    group by cast(a.date_started as date) ,a.id_a

)
SELECT cast(b.date_started as date) as b_date, 
    count(case when b.id is not null then id_b else null end) as units_b,
    case when cond1=something then ISNULL(sum(table_b.price),0) else null end as amount, 
FROM table_b b
LEFT JOIN prod_a
    ON prod_a.a_date = b.b_date 
where cast(b.b_date as date) >= dateadd(day,-21,getdate())
GROUP BY cast(b.b_date as date)
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions to achieve this.
One solution is to create a dummy table (with a WITH clause) of dates in a range but I am trying not to take that route or add a CASE to the main select statement to insert a 0 instead of Null when there is no b.id.

Comment: `Cross apply` in place of you `left join` will bring in dates from Product_a. But this will not show dates where neither product sold

Comment: In case you haven't done so already, store dates using a date data type. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query